# Why does my systemd script not work properly

Tags: systemd

I have this systemd script.
I reload using `systemctl daemon-reload`, and start it with `systemctl start myserver.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/user/project/bin/server.js
User=user
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I execute `/usr/bin/node /home/user/project/bin/server.js` as `user` in the terminal, it executes just fine.

The reason why it has to be `user` is that the script uses `expressjs` which is only installed for `user`.

Why does my service not run, but just exit with status=1/FAILURE?

Comment: What do you see in the output from `journalctl -xe` and `systemctl status myserver.service`?

Comment: You've asked an FAQ about [script runs in a terminal but not via systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239)